# Can't use live USB

Tags: liveusb

I'm having troubles with USB bootloaders. I tried two kinds of them but after loading files, it's stuck  at windows logo (the first boot image is windows installation, the second one is Minitool power data recovery which I assume also uses  windows logo):
[image: windows logo after loading files]
However the boot images worked well in another PC. I guess something is wrong in BIOS settings but I don't know what that is.

Comment: @John my bios does support UEFI

Comment: Restart in BIOS and reset the BIOS settings to Default. Save these, exit and then try again. If that is successful, update BIOS if there is one just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the hard drive itself, I was able to boot into USB stick. So I think it was because of the HDD.